# PostgreSQL - How to use window function to pull the max value from a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, window-functions

I am a beginner, so apologies in advance for simple/non-technical terminology.

I have a table where each row shows the company name, day/month/year, and how many visits they received in that day. My goal is to show which company had the highest number of visits for January 2018.

I was able to find how many visits each company received in January 2018 using this query:

```
select to_char(datecolumn,'Mon') as monthkey, extract(year from datecolumn) as yearkey, companyname, sum(visits) as sumvisits
from t1
where monthkey = 'Jan' and yearkey = '2018'
group by monthkey, yearkey, companyname
order by companyname
```

Now I need to use a window function to find the max value of sumvisits of January along with the corresponding company, but I'm stuck.

I've tried partitioning by month:

```
select companyname, monthkey, max(sumvisits) over (partition by monthkey) as maxvisits
from (select to_char(f_date,'Mon') as monthkey, extract(year from f_date) as yearkey, companyname, sum(visits) as sumvisits
from t1
where monthkey = 'Jan' and yearkey = '2018'
group by monthkey, yearkey, dealername
order by companyname)
```

But this query just gives me the max visits of one company and lists it for every company.

I don't think I should use the limit function or anything like that because the query needs to be applicable to multiple months.

I want to to see:

```
monthkey yearkey companyname sumvisits
Jan      2018    ABCInc     5000
```

Can someone please help advise what I'm doing wrong/point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select to_char(datecolumn,'Mon') as monthkey, extract(year from datecolumn) as yearkey, companyname, 
       sum(visits) as sumvisits
from t1
where monthkey = 'Jan' and yearkey = '2018'
group by monthkey, yearkey, companyname
order by sumvisits desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I can't use limit because this needs to work with multiple months as well

Comment: @Meeko . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked, and this one is obviously about a single month.  If you have a different question, please ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: In my initial question, I noted that it needs to be applicable to multiple months, but I can ask a new one too. Thanks!

Comment: @Meeko . . . This is applicable to any month you like by changing the `where` clause.  Hence, it answers the question that you asked.